# Проблема с Django "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Здравствуйте, работаю с Django 1.11

Создал приложение под название `blog`, в urls проекта имеется такой код

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', include('landing.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls.')),
]
```

в самом же `blog` имеется urls файл :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', views.blog, name='blog'),
]
```

Так же есть файл `models` -

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import datetime

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True),

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    text = models.CharField()
    date_post = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

файл `views` :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def blog(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html')
```

`admin`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Category, Post

admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Post)
```

и чистый `html` файл

При запуске команды `python3 manage.py makemigrations` выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File     "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File     "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/django/psy_site/psy_site/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls.')),
  File "/home/milkiweed/python/venvs/tango_with_django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 945, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.urls.'; 'blog.urls' is not a package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась. 
В файле `urls.py` была лишняя запятая `url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls.')),`